# Is there a way to insert a step between pre-processing and compilation for GCC or cl.exe?

Tags: c, gcc, cl

I am trying to instrument a big C code base. The code base can be built with GCC and MS cl.exe. The code base contains millions of lines. I am trying to instrument it for code coverage. Because the runtime environment is special, I have to do the instrumentation in a special way.

I have written a transformation tool that can do the instrumentation. But it cannot handle the macro expansion, header file includes, etc. In other words, it must work **after the pre-processing stage**.

I may not have enough time to write a C pre-processor. Since the code base is built with GCC/cl.exe, I am wondering if it is possible to inject my transformation step into the GCC or cl.exe compilation process. Like this:

```
GCC/cl.exe pre-process  ->  (My transformation) -> GCC/cl.exe compilation
```

Is that possible?

### ADD 1

So far, all the answers revolve around the GCC. How about the Microsoft cl.exe? I tried the [/P](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6.aspx) option which will emit the preprocess result to a file. But the result contains many lines like below:

```
#line 1306 "<some file path>"
```

I am trying to resolve it.

OK, I solved it,. Specify both `/P` and `/EP` can suppress the `#line` directive.

### ADD 2

The output of specifying both `"/P /EP"` for `cl.exe` is a `*.i` file without `#line` directives. It's a valid C source file. So it can be **directly** fed into the `cl.exe`. I just rename the original C file and use the `*.i` file for instrumentation and then the build process.

(Notice to avoid some header file included through `/FI`. That can cause some duplicated definition error. Should remove them because their content are already included in the `*.i` file.)

### ADD 3

I can just use the `/P` switch. The `#line` directive doesn't jeopardize the compilation and can be recognized by a C parser. And without such info, it's difficult to back-track from the instrumented code to the original `c` source code, as pointed out by Jonathan Leffler.

### ADD 4

The instrumentation is not easy. For example, the block separation for block-based code coverage is tricky according to [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/phuene/2007/05/03/code-coverage-instrumentation/) (note the block 4).

Comment: Yes, it is possible; no, it isn't particularly easy. There's usually a separate C preprocessor, often called `cpp`.  You could run that with appropriate arguments on the original source, then instrument the output, then finish the compilation with the full compiler (except that there'd be nothing significant for the second preprocessor to do unless your instrumentation added extra material that needed further preprocessing. There are options (usually `-E` and/or `-P`) to the compiler to run the preprocessor only — you can post-process the output and feed the result into the compiler again.

Comment: Use a makefile to manage the 3 steps Jonathan mentioned: Run compiler in preprocessor mode only / Run your tool / Compile

Comment: The essential thing @Jonathan tells you here that gcc is a just "compiler driver" which evaluates command line arguments and then lets other programs do the actual work by calling them with their specific arguments with the temporary files produced by earlier stages (or through pipelines). You can call them all separately, or instruct gcc to stop and later resume at a given stage.

Comment: How big is the code base (millions of lines)? How much time can you afford spending?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Millions of lines. I am trying to instrument it for code coverage. Because the runtime environment is special, I have to do the instrumentation in a special way.

Comment: That should go into the question.

Comment: My answer does now address MSVC in outline (it is similar to GCC).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible; no, it isn't particularly easy.

There's usually a separate C preprocessor, often called `cpp`.  You could run that with appropriate arguments on the original source, then instrument the output, then finish the compilation with the full compiler — except that there'd be nothing significant for the second preprocessor phase to do unless your instrumentation added extra material that needed further preprocessing.

Similarly, there are options (often `-E` and/or `-P`) to the compiler to run the preprocessor only — you can post-process the output from that and feed the result into the compiler again.

For example, given a starting file `file1.pp`, you might use GCC (`gcc`):

```
gcc -E file1.pp …other-options-as-needed… -o file1.i
transformer file1.i file1.c
gcc -c file1.c …more-options-as-needed…
gcc -o instrumented-program file1.o …other-object-files-and-options…
```

I'm assuming your program is called `transformer` and that it takes an arbitrary input file name (`file1.i`) and writes to an arbitrary output file (`file1.c`).  You can add other options to this as needed, of course.

You then fettle the build procedures in your `makefile` to handle this automatically.  Under the old (POSIX) rules, you would add a suffix `.pp` to `.SUFFIXES` and then provide rules to compile `.pp` to `.o` (and maybe to a `.c` file, and maybe direct to an executable file).  You'd want to move the intermediate `file1.i` file automatically most of the time, but you might need to preserve it occasionally.

Consider whether to create a 'compiler' shell script that generates the instrumented `.c` file from the `.pp` file in one fell swoop.  Be aware that handling such programs can become quite intricate — but if you can keep it simple, it can be very helpful.  One advantage of such a script is that you can make it present the same external (command line) interface on both Windows and Unix, and just arrange for the internals to deal with GCC vs Clang vs MSVC vs any other compiler.

You could start with a `.c` file (instead of the `.pp` file I hypothesized), but you'd need a systematic way of handling the name — you don't butcher the original `.c` file.  Again, this may be easier with the shell script creating an instrumented `.o` (or `.obj`) file from the C source — it can deal with the complexities of file naming.

Remember that the `#line` directive allows you to specify line numbers and file names to the C compiler proper; it is designed to assist with preprocessed files (e.g. the output from Yacc/Bison contains `#line` directives to identify where the code comes from in the original grammar (`.y`) file).

When GCC preprocesses a file, its output contains a variation on the `#line` directive.  When I preprocessed a file called `alloc3d19.c` which had the first 4 lines:

```
/* SO 4885-6272 */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

then GCC generated output starting:

```
# 1 "alloc3d19.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "alloc3d19.c"


# 1 "/usr/include/stdlib.h" 1 3 4
# 61 "/usr/include/stdlib.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/Availability.h" 1 3 4
# 202 "/usr/include/Availability.h" 3 4
# 1 "/opt/gcc/v7.3.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.4.0/7.3.0/include-fixed/AvailabilityInternal.h" 1 3 4
# 203 "/usr/include/Availability.h" 2 3 4
# 62 "/usr/include/stdlib.h" 2 3 4
```

where there isn't a `line` after the `#` but it means basically the same, except for the numbers after the file names.  (The two blanks lines are the comment and the blank line in the source; it doesn't reach `stdio.h` until line number 1638 of the output file.  With 73 lines of source code, the output was 2091 lines, of which 292 were `#line` directives.)  Your transformer needs to handle — possibly by ignoring — such lines.  You might omit them, but then back-tracking to the source is hard.  You might need to add some `#line` directives to disguise where your code was added.  You might need to change the file name temporarily so that any message related to your instrumentation are separate from those related to the original source code.

Answer (score 2):

With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (specifically) you might consider writing your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) (which will transform not textual files, but internal GCC representations). You might also consider [libclang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html). But it is not easy (you could spend weeks or months of work).

Take into account that: GCC is a complex software (about ten millions lines of code) and you'll need a lot of work to learn its internal representations ([Generic/TREE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GENERIC.html) & [GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html)). Also, the plugin API is not completely stable, so you might need to change your plugin code when going from GCC 7 to GCC 8 (to be released in spring 2018).

I have collected and wrote some material (slightly old) about GCC plugins on my old [GCC MELT documentation](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/docum.html) page.

Another possibility might be to use some *other* preprocessor (perhaps [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) or [m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html)) and generate some instrumented C or C++ code from some other files. Be aware that generating C or C++ code is a common habit (look into Qt [moc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html), into [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) for examples ...).

Whatever approach you are taking, **it won't be easy** in general (unless your particular code base is following some consistent conventions). In some cases (small code base of only a hundred thousand lines) transforming the code manually might be simpler.

BTW, if you use your compiler to generate preprocessed files, you might (easily) remove the emitted `#line` or `#` lines with e.g. some `grep -v '^#'` (but you might also want to keep them and/or parse them).

Notice that instrumenting automatically a code is harder than what you think .... (and the main issues are not to ignore `#` lines).

Comment: Yes, the instrumentation is not easy. For a blocked-based code coverage, the block separation is tricky. As mentioned here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/phuene/2007/05/03/code-coverage-instrumentation/